# Find elements not in smaller character vector list but in big list

Tags: r, list, character, subset

I have the two big and small list. I want to know which of the elements in big list are not in smaller list. The list consists of property

```
([1] "character"           "vector"              "data.frameRowLabels"
[4] "SuperClassMethod"
```

Here is small example and error I am getting

```
 A <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
 B <- c("A", "B", "C")
  new <- A[!B]
Error in !B : invalid argument type
```

The expected output is new <- c("D")

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at `help("%in%")` - there's an example all the way at the bottom of that page that addresses this situation.

```
A <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
B <- c("A", "B", "C")
(new <- A[which(!A %in% B)])

# [1] "D"
```

**EDIT:**

As Tyler points out, I should take my own advice and read the support documents. `which()` is unnecessary when using `%in%` for this example. So,

```
(new <- A[!A %in% B])

# [1] "D"
```

Comment: the which is unnecessary here.

Comment: @Tyler, You're right; I should take my own advice: from `help("%in%")`: "That %in% never returns NA makes it particularly useful in if conditions". I included `which` out of habit, since I've gotten burned without it. Here, it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

`!` only works on logical vectors.  `B` is not logical, which is what causes the error.  Decomposing the steps you're trying to make will show you this (i.e. `!B`).  In this case, you want to use `%in%` (or `match`).

```
A[!A %in% B]
```

To decompose the above code:

1. `A %in% B` creates a logical vector that is `TRUE` for values of `A`
   that exist in `B`.
2. `!A %in% B` negates (reverses) the logic in (1)
3. `A[!A %in% B]` returns the vector of elements that are `TRUE` in (2)

Answer (score 4):

While I think `sets` may help you to deal with different lists.

In your case, you can just use:

```
A <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
B <- c("A", "B", "C")

# to find difference
setdiff(A, B)

# to find intersect
intersect(A, B)

# to find union
union(A, B)
```